# is there a variable with the tag name generated by the maven-release-plugin?

Tags: maven-release-plugin

I'd like to run a custom maven step using the <kbd>completionGoals</kbd> option of the  maven-release-plugin. This steps need to know the tag name the maven-release-plugin used to tag the release commit. Is there a variable to access this tag name?

Comment: Interesting, but I don't have solution?Good question ... +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the release-plugin has "tagNameFormat" as configuration paramter. You could set that one to a variable and use it for your own purpose too?

The default is "@{project.artifactId}-@{project.version}" (see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#tagNameFormat) so you could just guess it that way if you know folks dont use that paramter.

since the released pom.xml will contain the tag url in ${project.scm.developerconnection} that may be an option as well.